# Rviz Tf breaks when I change fixed frame to odom frame

Tags: rviz, robot-localization, ros-humble, tf-tree

how are you all doing?

I've been trying to use the ros humble robot_localization package to estimate my robot's pose using odometry and imu data. The thing is, when the fixed frame is the base_footprint all the robot's TF are parsed ok.

[image]

When I set my odom frame as the fixed frame some of my transformations break.

[image]

But if I look at the broadcasted frames the tf tree seems normal.

[image]

Although it isn´t something critical to me, it is bothering me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/tf` timestamp values are not consistent. Most likely you have some nodes with `use_sim_time` parameter set to true, and other nodes with it set to false.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!